# Invalid Comparison of Complex Error

Tags: python

I have the code below, where  `temp[count]` contains some `complex` variables. But I get the error `TypeError: Invalid comparison of complex` in the line `if temp[count] > 0 and isinstance(temp[count], complex) == 0`.

```
if temp[count] > 0 and isinstance(temp[count], complex) == 0:
    print(temp[count])
    count += 1
```

**Edit**:

```
if not isinstance(temp[count], complex): 
    print('T', temp[count]) 
    if temp[count] > 0: 
        print('Made it')
```

`print('T', temp[count])` prints a Complex number and thus I get the same error as before. Also, I did a print('type', type(temp[count])) and it gives `<'class sympy.core.add.Add'>`. How do I resolve this?

`type[count]` contains `-1.5 + 0.86*I, -1.5 - 0.86*I, -2, -1.0 + 1.0*I`

Comment: @Wooble I want to `print(temp[count])` if `temp[count]` is not a `complex`.

Comment: @Wooble There is clearly an error. I think its pretty obvious my question is how to solve this error. I've seen many such postings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) -

> The `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` operators will raise a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number.

Also, it does not make sense to compare complex numbers to anything (other than equality) .

If all you want to do is print the number if its not complex, as you gave in the comments -

> I want to print(temp[count]) if temp[count] is not a complex.

You can do -

```
if not isinstance(temp[count], complex):
    print(temp[count])
```

---

From latest update in question, seems like `temp` contains more elements of different types , which are causing issue, if you only want to print elements of certain type and ignore the rest, then you can use `isinstance()` passing in only those types in a tuple as the second argument. Example (for int and float) -

```
if isinstance(temp[count], (int, float)):
    print(temp[count])
```

The above is just an example to show how to check if a particular element is one of multiple types, you can do similarly with all the types you want.

Comment: I still have an issue with this. So I used your answer and wrote `if not isinstance(temp[count], complex):
                    print('T', temp[count])
                    if temp[count] > 0:
                        print('Made it')` And somehow `print('T', temp[count])` results in a Complex number being printed.

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest code you used? and maybe an example input for temp ?

Comment: Is your requirement to only print when the `temp[Count]` is of particular type? Seems like there are more type of elements in `temp` , if so which all type is that?

Comment: @FixIncome Please check the latest update, is that something similar to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If `temp[count]` is *guaranteed* to be a `complex` (but potentially with 0 for its imaginary *part*) and you're looking to get the complex numbers that have a imaginary part equal to 0, just get the imaginary part of `temp[count]` using `.imag` and compare it to 0:

```
if temp[count].imag != 0:
    print(temp[count])
    count += 1
```

Otherwise, if you are looking to get the non-complex numbers (i.e., you even want to exclude `(0+0j)` and `(2+0j)`), use `not isinstance(...)`:

```
if not isinstance(temp[count], complex):
    print(temp[count])
    count += 1
```